# Is it possible for a US President to be an autocrat while remaining within the boundaries of the US constitution?

Tags: united-states, president

Is it possible for a US president to be autocratic while maintaining the letter or spirit of the law?

Comment: The story goes: As Franklin left the convention he was asked a similar question and his famous reply was "A republic, if you can keep it." Which implies an important framer thought that it could become a monarchy.

Answer (score 3):

An autocrat has absolute power.

Amongst many other examples, the [United States Constitution](https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/constitution-transcript) states in [Article I(7)(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentment_Clause):

> Every Bill which shall have passed the House of Representatives and
>   the Senate, shall, before it become a Law, be presented to the
>   President of the United States: If he approve he shall sign it, but if
>   not he shall return it, with his Objections to that House in which it
>   shall have originated, who shall enter the Objections at large on
>   their Journal, and proceed to reconsider it. If after such
>   Reconsideration two thirds of that House shall agree to pass the Bill,
>   it shall be sent, together with the Objections, to the other House, by
>   which it shall likewise be reconsidered, and if approved by two thirds
>   of that House, it shall become a Law.

So this is one example of the President's power not being absolute: if two thirds of both Houses of Congress agree, the Presidential veto can be overridden.

Therefore the President's power is not absolute; he cannot strictly be an autocrat.

Other examples include the Supreme Court's ability to strike down laws as unconstitutional and the ability of two-thirds of the states to change the constitution without any action in Washington.

A President can be 'autocratic' in a more subjective sense if they merely act as though they had absolute power, but the intention behind the separation of powers is that they cannot actually be an autocrat.

Comment: Nice answer, but you don't need to discuss the veto override to explain why the president's power is not absolute: the president cannot make laws unilaterally; they have to originate in congress in the first place.